# Delete query with sweet alert confirmation in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I have CRUD table. When I click on delete, a confirmation box appears, but i want to change this confirmation box with **sweet alert**

*javascript*

```
function delete_unit(id){
        if(confirm('Hapus Data?'))// <== I wanna change it with sweetalert
        {
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('C_unit/delete')?>/" + id,
                type : "POST",
                dataType : "JSON",
                success : function(data)
                {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Gagal menghapus data');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Sweet Alert documentation: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: problem is, i just don't know how to change classic confirmation with sweet alert

Comment: @Z.Norz please check my answer you may have to change some properties based on the version but you have to use promises for the confirmation in sweetalert.I have used 1.1.3 for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the below code . Also the docs for detail help on this 
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/.

```js
    function delete_unit(id){       
          swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this data!",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                        url : "<?php echo base_url('C_unit/delete')?>/" + id,
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType : "JSON",
                        success : function(data)
                        {
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert('Gagal menghapus data');
                        }
                 });
                }
        });
     }
```

Here is a working Fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/s7zd9822/